# Clob size in bytes

Tags: oracle

I have a database with the below NLS settings

```
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  - AL16UTF16

NLS_CHARACTERSET - AL32UTF8
```

There's a table with a clob column storing a **base64 encoded** data.
Since the characters are mostly english and letters, I would assume each character takes up 1 byte only as clob using the charset of NLS_CHARACTERSET for encoding.

With a inline enabled clob column, the clob will be stored inline unless it goes more that 4096 bytes in size. However, when I tried to store a set of data with 2048 chars, I found that it is not stored inline (By checking the table DBA_TABLES).  So does it mean each character is not using only 1 byte? Can anyone elaborate on this?

Another test added: 
Create a table with clob column with chunk size 8kb so that initial segment size is 65536 bytes.
After insert a row with 32,768 chars in clob column. The 2nd extent creation can be told by querying dba_segments.

Comment: Is you column really a `CLOB` or `NCLOB` ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux It is CLOB indeed. I even tried to create a new table and the observation is the same.

Comment: Since the CLOB contains base64 encoded data, why not base64 *decode* it and store the bytes in a BLOB instead? First you would halve the bytes because of the CLOB stored as UCS-2 (Rustys answer), then you would reduce the size 25% further? The drawback would be that you probably would have to base64 *encode* it when you query it out, so it would be a choice between using more space (CLOB) or using more CPU (BLOB with decode/encode).

Comment: @KimBergHansen This is a good suggestion. But I cant do anything with the definition as it's already in production. I am just trying to evaluate the disk usage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch6unicode.htm#r2c1-t12

It says:

> Data in CLOB columns is stored in a format that is compatible with
>   UCS-2 when the database character set is multibyte, such as UTF8 or
>   AL32UTF8. This means that the storage space required for an English
>   document doubles when the data is converted

So it looks like CLOB internally stores everything as UCS-2 (Unicode), i.e. 2 bytes fixed per symbol. Consequently, it stores inline 4096/2 = 2048 chars.

Comment: I assume Oracle use fixed-size encoding internally to speed-up direct access to characters at arbitrary position. Probably?